# Calling Java method from JSP in Struts 2

Tags: jsp, struts2

I want to call Java method which returns me the array list and I want to add that array list to the drop-down list in JSP. When user select one value from the drop-down list that value is stored in the variable type

```
<form action="Config.action" method="post">
<table width="600" height="34" align="center" border="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><br>
<%     
    Config c = new Config();
    ArrayList<String> names = c.populate();
    out.print("<table>  <tr><select>");

    for (String s : names) 
    {
        out.print("<option value="+s+">"+s+"</option>");
    }    
%>    
</select></table>
```

Comment: Does using tags to refer to domain objects not work for you? for example, <s:select list="Some name" name="dropdownname"
    listValue="%{name of the collection used on java model}

Answer (score 3):

Use action properties to get/set the names

```
private String name;
//getter and setter

public ArrayList<String> getNames(){
  Config c = new Config();
  return c.populate();
}
```

JSP:

```
<form action="Config.action" method="post">
<table width="600" height="34" align="center" border="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><br>
<s:select name="name" list="names"/>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Index.jsp Page,After Body tag add this line,

```
<s:bean name="controller.FindList" var="my"> </s:bean>

  <s:select 
    list="name" 
    name="name_list" />
```

FindList.class

```
   private List<String> name=new ArrayList<String>();// Setter method

   public ArrayList<String> getNames(){
           Config c = new Config();
            name=c.populate();
           return name;
   }
```

no need to action controller code in struts.xml

Answer (score 0):

In this case you must have to call ajax function which you can achieve by using DWR with combination of Jquery.
See the below link

[`DWR+STRUTS 2`](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.1.x/docs/dwr-plugin.html)

Comment: There is no need for dwr, because you can call S2 actions with ajax.