# How to call Java methods from JSP page in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl

I am new to Struts 2, (switched from jsp to Struts2)

I have 3 java class files and 4 jsp pages in a Struts2 application
I have to call 2 different methods of one java class file (let class_01) 
from a jsp page (let `methodCallerJsp.jsp`)

In jsp I use Java bean as:

```
<jsp:useBean id="class_01-obj" class="package.class_01"/>
```

And then fetch method by:

```
class_01-obj.method_AA();
```

How can I do the same thing in Struts2?

Answer (score 0):

In Struts 2 you don't have to use `jsp:useBean` tag to get access to some bean properties/methods.

You also don't have to call JSP directly, everything is done through the action. The action class that you configure in the Struts configuration, i.e. `struts.xml` could be used instead of `jsp:useBean`.

You can also configure a method of this class used to map the action. When action is called Struts instantiates an action bean defined in the configuration and populates its properties. This instance is available in JSP that the action returns as a result. To use these properties or methods you should use OGNL, or JSTL EL.

Comment: Thanks for reply
can you give me any link on this

Comment: I think you have a lot of related links on the right side, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25181452/573032) is another one.